# How many members have made comments approved for an article?

Tags: comments, author, count

Good afternoon.
Please, I would like to have a function that calculates for each post displayed (one by one), not how many comments, but how many are the authors of the comments for the post viewed at that time.
Something like this:

```
function commentCount() {
global $wpdb; 

$count = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT COUNT(distinct comment_author) FROM' .$wpdb->comments. 'WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND comment_post_ID = $postID');
    echo $count;     
 }
```

Thank you very much!.

---

@ s_ha_dum:
Goog Afternoon.
To explain better, I enclose a picture of the condition that I got on the page of a post, at the beginning of the field of the comments.
![enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNElu.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNElu.jpg

Comment: Hi, can you be more precise. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Hi, I would like that in the single post page, when it begins the space of the comments, it can be possible shown the number of the authors of the comments (in addition to the number of comments), because it is their large presence that establishes the importance of the post, not quantity comments. So, I may write further: The topic of this post is a little later, or the topic of this post is a lot of interest, or the topic of this post was not considered interesting.
You know, sometimes the authors of the posts answer with very few words, just to increase the number of comments.

Comment: Sorry, but this has gone well beyond the scope of the original question and is now pushing "work for me for free" territory-- see the [faq]. I would suggest that you vote/accept an answer based on the original question (or not, your choice) as _that question has been answered_. Take what you have from this question, try to get things working and come back with more questions that are more specific. To answer this at this point I feel like I would need to write a plugin, and I still don't know what the several "phrases" are, much less those conditional images.

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP is wrong but what you are doing looks like it should work.

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var(
    'SELECT COUNT(distinct comment_author) 
    FROM ' .$wpdb->comments. ' 
    WHERE comment_approved = 1 
    AND comment_post_ID = '.$post->ID
);
echo $count;
```

Precisely, you were trying to use a variable inside single quotes, which doesn't work. Variables don't expand inside single quotes. And you did not have spaces in the string where they needed to be so you were generating invalid SQL. I don't know where your `$postid` variable was coming from but inside a Loop `$post->ID` works so I used that.

There might be other ways to do it but I can't tell unless you can add more context and detail to the question.

Here is a more elaborate example which includes several pieces of information that I think the OP might be asking for.

```
function get_commentCount_wpse_98315() { 
  global $wpdb; 
  $id = get_the_ID();
  $comment_data = $wpdb->get_row('
    SELECT 
    COUNT(distinct comment_author) as comment_count,
    COUNT(comment_ID) as comment_author_count,
    ("No idea what this is") as phrases
    FROM '.$wpdb->comments.'  WHERE comment_post_ID = '.$id
  ); 
//   var_dump($comment_data);
  echo implode(' | ',$comment_data);
}
```

Comment: Good evening. I tried also your code, but unfortunatelly it's non working too. I just put others element about my question above, in answer to Mrs Rarst. Definetely, i need the count of authors per each post and this counting must be shown just on the middle column above the section of comment, visible and updated when somebody open the post. Thank you!.

Comment: @Giacinto : I don't know what you think "doesn't work" but when I paste this into a template it does return the number of authors who have commented on the post, so long as the `$post` object is set correctly. And that _seems to be_ what the question is asking for. If I have missed something please point out exactly what doesn't work. Are you looking for something to tell you how many authors have commented on one page of paginated comments?

Comment: You are very gentle, thank you. I tried, Itried I tried and finally the below is the code that workes: function get_commentCount() {
    global $wpdb;
    $count = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT COUNT(distinct comment_author) FROM ' . $wpdb->comments. ' WHERE comment_post_ID = "' . get_the_ID() . '"');
echo $count;
}. Now I need some conditions for assembly together comment number, phrases and autor number.

Comment: Sorry, but this is the message of error produced with your code - Fatal error: Call to a member function get_var() on a non-object...

Comment: That will happen if you try to use `$wpdb` before the `global $wpdb` object has been instantiated. You are running the function too soon, somehow. Please edit your question to include _all_ of what you want. What is are "comment number", "phrases", and "author number"?

Comment: @ s_ha_dum:
Good Afternoon.
To explain better, I would like enclose a picture of the condition that I got on the page of a post, at the beginning of the field of the comments, but the system doesn't permit to me. I don't know how better I can explain you, my english is very bad!. Maybe by e.mail?.

Comment: I expanded my answer but I can't do better unless you can provide a better explanation.